# Unable to install files with apt-get: "unable to locate package"

Tags: apt

I'm having issues with my ubuntu server version 12.04 installed on a HP550 laptop, when i try `sudo apt-get install <programname>`, e.g `apache2` it will not work, saying `E: Unable to locate package apache2`.

I have tried to look/edit the sources. but they will not work either the `gedit` command is broken too, i am trying `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` for those wondering, is this a case of the computer network not configured properly? it downloaded a language pack easily enough in the installation though. how do i fix this? a prompt reply would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to issue `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install the package?

Comment: `gedit` is a GUI tool; and as you've probably noticed there is no GUI on an ubuntu server by default. Try using `nano` instead. What's more, you'll need to run the command with `sudo` (IE `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`) as files in the /etc/ directory are normally write-protected and only writable by the root user.

Answer (score 109):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install the package. After installation the system doesn't have an up-to-date package list so you won't be able to find the package.

Once you've done this you should be able to install as normal.

Comment: Had this problem with the docker debian:jessie file.  You need to set a 'RUN apt-get update' before you try to install anything.

Answer (score 17):

#### Check your /etc/apt/sources.list

This is an *example* sources.list file.  I have used the program **net-select-apt** to chose the fastest mirror for me.  Also, notice this is for **12.04/Precise**.

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe
deb http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.symnds.com/ubuntu/ precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

#### Update your apt

`sudo apt-get update`

#### Check if apt can find apache2

`sudo apt-cache search apache2`

#### Install apache2

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

#### Optional additional repositories

Here are a few *optional* repos you can go ahead and add to the bottom of your **sources.list**.

```
#Chromium
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/stable/ubuntu precise main
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes try writing `sudo apt-get update`
This will download the source package list.
apache2 would be on that updated list

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue too. I was informed that I need to download the program dependencies or the "package" before I can install the program on Ubuntu. You can try `sudo apt-get update` first.

I assume Apache is a third party vendor so this would be the reason Ubuntu cannot find the package. Try going to the Apache site itself and look for packages you can download and open with Ubuntu that are for Ubuntu or Linux. Then try the `sudo apt-get install <program>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apache2 is the package name for the open source http server `httpd` from the apache foundation. It's definitely in the repositories.