# "Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80", why?

Tags: apt

After installing a fresh copy of ubuntu 14.04 downloaded from ubuntu.com 
I am trying to install some packages be it nodejs or apache2 it always says  name not found. 
I searched a bit and found some answers here

[Unable to install files with apt-get: "unable to locate package"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216287/unable-to-install-files-with-apt-get-unable-to-locate-package)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204637

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2225203

but no solution worked for me. I already have all the sources enabled -

[image]

Also, tried `sudo apt-get update` many times but it returns

Some output like this saying unable to download or find packages or something like that -

```
    Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en_IN
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/partner/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/partner/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_IN  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/universe/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

sudo: unable to resolve host unknown-GG003AA-ACJ-SR5160IL
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                                                                                     

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                                                                                             

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                                                                                           

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease                                                                                            

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                         

Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                                                                                             

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                                                                                       
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                                                                                        

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                                                                                              

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                                                                                      
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                                        
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                                                 

Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                                               
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease     

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg   
  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:
Reading package lists... Done


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-proposed/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 80.112.143.217:80:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should i do now

Comment: Try another ubuntu mirror close to your geographic location. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors Unless you are compiling, you do NOT need the sources enabled.

Comment: Also, are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error with the same IP adress appears at each connection tentative to a server providing Ubuntu package, I think that you've configured a web proxy using the IP 80.112.143.217 and port 80.

A quick search in Google shows me that indeed this IP is associated with a public web proxy.

Currently it is not responding to any queries so I may be not running now. Try removing the proxy setting : `System settings` -> `Network` -> `Network proxy`. Remove or change the proxy adress to one which is functioning and click `Apply system wide`.

Comment: To use a proxy with apt see http://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy . If the op is using a proxy, s/he should update the question.

Comment: oh, yeah i used a graphical tool to try proxies, but i thought the proxy would be cleared after reboot. guess that did not happen. Thanks for help.

Comment: your response help me to figure out that it was problem with network connection. Hence, I disconnect and connect my network and everything starts working. thanks @benoit !

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using a proxy to connect with repositories. Maybe the configuration file in /etc/apt/apt.conf is wrong. 
Please check contents. It should be in the form:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
```

username cannot be an email!!! - username and password can be empty - remove < >

If you are able to connect directly to internet simply delete the /etc/apt/apt.conf file. (Its also recommendable to backup it first :) )
All this information applyes to ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 (as far i know)